# Using (raw) Sqlite with VS 2019 NUNit Test project for .NET Core 5

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

**Context Environment:**

- MS Win 10 Pro (OS Buld 19041.1110),
- VS 2019 (build 16.10.3),
- NUNit .NET Core Test Project,
- .NET Core 5.0

**Code:**

```
[Test]
public void Test4()
{
    var sqliteDbFullPath = @"{your sqliteDbFullPath here}";
    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={sqliteDbFullPath}"))
    {
        connection.Open(); // <= system exception is raised on run-time for this code line
        // ...
    }
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

**Error Message:**

System.Exception : You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().
If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().

**Installed NUGet Packages:**

- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 5.0.8
- SQLitePCLRaw.core 2.0.4

**Questions:**

- How to make this test project running successfully?
- What other (NUGet packages) or DLLs have to be installed/referenced?
- Do I need to manually build Sqlite libs for my context environment?

**NB:** Please post your answer if you have 100% working tested solution only. Thank you.

Comment: Or you could look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/custom-versions?tabs=netcore-cli) for custom providers.

Comment: @Mark Benningfield: I have found the solution - please see my own answer. The things are getting really simple with .NET 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

It happens it's enough for the **.NET 5**-based *console* and *NUnit* test projects just to install NUGet package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite via Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
Restoring packages for ... NetCore.NUnit.TestProject.csproj...
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 5.0.8.
Committing restore...
Writing assets file to disk. Path: ... NetCore.NUnit.TestProject\obj\project.assets.json
Restored ... NetCore.NUnit.TestProject.csproj (in 244 ms).
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 5.0.8' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 5.0.8' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 2.0.4' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'SQLitePCLRaw.core 2.0.4' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3 2.0.4' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl 2.0.4' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Successfully installed 'System.Memory 4.5.3' to NetCore.NUnit.TestProject
Executing nuget actions took 403 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.3812238
```

Then the "magic" happens and Sqlite connections are opened successfully and data retrieved OK.

I was wrong with my initial actions trying to install _Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core_and related packages, which resulted in run-time error messages.